# alphanumeric sort in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I perform sorting in following xslt 1.0
Below are the input xmls and output expected

input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input>
<a attr1="2B"></a>
<a attr1="0003"></a>
<a attr1="1"></a>
<a attr1="AA"></a>
<a attr1="2A"></a>
<a attr1="AB"></a>
<a attr1="2"></a>
<a attr1="1A"></a>
<a attr1="04"></a>
<a attr1="3C"></a>
</input>
```

Output expected:

```
<output>    
<a attr1="1"></a>
<a attr1="1A"></a>  
<a attr1="2"></a>
<a attr1="2A"></a>
<a attr1="2B"></a>
<a attr1="0003"></a>
<a attr1="3C"></a>
<a attr1="04"></a>
<a attr1="AA"></a>
<a attr1="AB"></a>
</output>
```

Comment: why is `0003` after `2B` (and similarly `04` after `3C`)?

Comment: Because 0003 is equivalent to 3 and 04 is equivalent to 4.

Comment: Would "0A" come before "1" or before "AA" (after "04")? Would the leading 0 in this case be counted as a numerical value, or ignored as are the 0s in the other numerical values?

Comment: @AntonH The order would be 04,0A,AA. So leading 0 will be ignored.

Comment: Are the @attr1 values always number first, if any, then characters?  Can there be multiple numbers and multiple letter in any order?

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to use `sort` function ignoring zeros (in your case) and inside loop **/input/a**, see XSL below(**edited**):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>               
            <xsl:for-each select="/input/a">                               
                <xsl:sort select="not(number(format-number(translate(@attr1, translate(@attr1, '1234567890', ''), ''), '#')))" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:sort select="number(format-number(translate(@attr1, translate(@attr1, '1234567890', ''), ''), '#'))" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>                    
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </output>   
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So even if your XML is more complicated(extended primary) as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input>
<a attr1="2B"></a>
<a attr1="0003"></a>
<a attr1="1"></a>
<a attr1="AA"></a>
<a attr1="2A"></a>
<a attr1="AB"></a>
<a attr1="2"></a>
<a attr1="1A"></a>
<a attr1="04"></a>
<a attr1="3C"></a>
<a attr1="7"></a>
<a attr1="5K"></a>
<a attr1="100"></a>
<a attr1="10"></a>
<a attr1="11M"></a>
<a attr1="00015"></a>
<a attr1="15A"></a>
</input>
```

Result will be as expected:

```
<output>
    <a attr1="1"/>
    <a attr1="1A"/>
    <a attr1="2"/>
    <a attr1="2A"/>
    <a attr1="2B"/>
    <a attr1="0003"/>
    <a attr1="3C"/>
    <a attr1="04"/>
    <a attr1="5K"/>
    <a attr1="7"/>
    <a attr1="10"/>
    <a attr1="11M"/>
    <a attr1="00015"/>
    <a attr1="15A"/>
    <a attr1="100"/>
    <a attr1="AA"/>
    <a attr1="AB"/>
</output>
```

And result from primary input XML transformation:

```
<output>
    <a attr1="1"/>
    <a attr1="1A"/>
    <a attr1="2"/>
    <a attr1="2A"/>
    <a attr1="2B"/>
    <a attr1="0003"/>
    <a attr1="3C"/>
    <a attr1="04"/>
    <a attr1="AA"/>
    <a attr1="AB"/>
</output>
```

Comment: What if there is a following zero? As in 10A. Then 10A would sort, before 2A.  And, I'm curious about why the sort datatype is qname.

Comment: @Bluewood66 You are right, it will work with it's concrete example.

Comment: Why are you using qname as the data type?

Comment: @Bluewood66 Please see edited version, looks like right now it is more dynamic.

Comment: @O.F. I am getting somehow the following output.  AA and AB are sholwn before 1.                  
 <output>
 <a attr1="AA"/>
 <a attr1="AB"/>
 <a attr1="1"/>
 <a attr1="1A"/>
 <a attr1="2"/>
 <a attr1="2A"/>
 <a attr1="2B"/>
 <a attr1="0003"/>
 <a attr1="3C"/>
 <a attr1="04"/>
</output>

Comment: @Vinayak It is very important to keep the order of blocks <sort> and order="ascending" in this blocks in XSL as below <xsl:sort select="format-number(translate(@attr1, translate(@attr1, '1234567890', ''), ''), '#')" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
 <xsl:sort select="translate(@attr1, '1234567890', '')" order="ascending" data-type="text" /> . For me with above XSL -  output is still as expected: <output><a attr1="1"/><a attr1="1A"/><a attr1="2"/><a attr1="2A"/><a attr1="2B"/><a attr1="0003"/><a attr1="3C"/><a attr1="04"/><a attr1="AA"/><a attr1="AB"/></output>

Comment: @O.F. I am using the same xsl (with no modification ). The order is AA,AB,1,1A,2,2A,2B,0003,3C,04.

Comment: @Vinayak Hmm, that’s strange..then try to play with order, e.g. change on “descending” in sort for “text”.

Comment: @Vinayak Or try also to change places of sort for your case.

Comment: @O.F. No luck. I still wonder how you are getting the correct output.

Comment: @Bluewood66 do you have correct output with my XSL?

Comment: @Vinayak I think I found what was the problem - when I did format-number on value as "AA" or "AB", it was giving 'NaN' and sort it before number values. But right now it should work, please check and let me know.

Comment: @Bluewood66 Thanks a lot for checking! I think I found out what was wrong, sort put first 'NaN' values for such 'AA' or 'AB'. I tried new trick with double sorting, please see newest editing of XSL above.

Comment: @O.F. Thank you for the updated answer. I feel it still needs improvement. Following is the output I got <output >            
 <a attr1="1"/>
 <a attr1="1A"/>
 <a attr1="VY1"/>
 <a attr1="N1"/>
 <a attr1="0AB1"/>
 <a attr1="AA1"/>
 <a attr1="A1"/>
 <a attr1="2"/>
 <a attr1="2A"/>
 <a attr1="2B"/>
 <a attr1="0003"/>
 <a attr1="3C"/>
 <a attr1="04"/>
 <a attr1="5K"/>
 <a attr1="7"/>
 <a attr1="10"/>
 <a attr1="11M"/>
 <a attr1="00015"/>
 <a attr1="15A"/>
 <a attr1="100"/>
 <a attr1="BC"/>
 <a attr1="AB"/>
 <a attr1="AA"/>
 <a attr1="0A"/>
</output>

Comment: @Vinayak For your concrete input example, when types of attribute values as number, number-letter(firstly - number, secondary-letter) or letters - it will work as expected. Please accept this solution for current case or extend your sort requirement by editing your question. Thanks.